# Hide sub-domain in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mobile, subdomain

I've been working with Apache for a few months but I've run into a problem I can't seem to solve. I'd like to hide my sub-domain (primarily for my mobile site). For example I've already written an .htaccess file that redirects mobile devices to m.example.com but now I'd like to hide the "m." on only mobile devices is this possible?

Please help!

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you must place all content on the same vhost. Then you could use *mod_rewrite* to change the internal path for the content without showing it to the user.

This is not possible with two different vhosts.